# Where is the function given by "which prompt" defined?

Tags: arch-linux, zsh

I am used to using "which stuff" do find the file that will be called when I use "stuff". I was quite surprised to see "which prompt" respond with

```
prompt () {
        local prompt_opts
        set_prompt "$@"
        (( $#prompt_opts )) && setopt noprompt{bang,cr,percent,subst} "prompt${^prompt_opts[@]}"
        true
}
```

on my Archlinux system. Where does this come from, and how do I make the prompt command avaliable inside the chroot environment I am currently building? (I just copied the other commands into it... that does not work here =) )

**Edit:** I am using zsh as my shell, maybe that changes something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're getting when you ran `which` is a a function, called `prompt`. The output is its definition.

You can see it using this command too:

```
$ declare -f prompt
```

#### Where's the prompt() function?

This is a bit trickier. You'll have to resort to using a tool such as `grep` to find the string "`prompt ()`". The usual places to look are as follows:

#### bash

(N.B. [Don't use `which` in bash, use `type` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then))

```
$ grep -R "prompt ()" .bashrc .bash_profile /etc/bashrc /etc/profile*
```

#### zsh

```
$ grep -R "prompt ()" <files>
```

From the man page, these are the files that `zsh` makes use of:

```
   $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
   $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
   $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
   $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
   $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout
   ${TMPPREFIX}*   (default is /tmp/zsh*)
   /etc/zshenv
   /etc/zprofile
   /etc/zshrc
   /etc/zlogin
   /etc/zlogout    (installation-specific - /etc is the default)
```

It should be in one of those locations. If it doesn't show up in any of those places then you'll need to expand your search. I would suggest looking for just the string "`prompt`".

Comment: Oddly enough, the behavior of outputting function definition when called with a function name is characteristic of `type` rather than `which`. I'm guessing ArchLinux redefines `which` somehow. I wouldn't know. But I guess the OP's real problem is determining which file defines the `prompt` function.

Comment: That is really nice to know, thank you! My immidiate problem is not solved by this ("prompt is a shell function"), but I learned something today =)

Comment: @Jens - sorry I didn't read the whole Q 8-). I've added a section on how to find prompt().

Comment: @JosephR. - thanks for pointing that out, updated Q. Should've read the whole thing 8-). BTW, I agree, never seen `which` show a function either, `type` makes more sense.

Comment: @Jens - see updates.

Comment: A `grep -R  "prompt ()" /etc /usr` later I found the function definitions in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/`. Thanks again =)

Comment: @Jens - yeah it's a bit of a archaeologist job using Unix sometimes 8-).

Comment: In zsh (as opposed to other shells such as Bourne, dash, bash or ksh), `which` is a builtin and can be used without compunction.

Comment: @Gilles So this `type`-like behavior of `which` is due to the `zsh` implementation rather than ArchLinux, right?

Comment: @JosephR. Indeed, there's nothing specific to Arch here.

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` by itself isn't useful: it's calling another function called `set_prompt`, you need this one as well (and all of its dependencies).

The first thing to look for would be an autoloaded function.

```
print -rl $fpath/prompt(N)
```

Barring that, search in your initialization files and in files on the function load path for the function definition.

```
grep -E '^ *function +prompt($|[^0-9A-Z_a-z])|^ *prompt *\(' ~/.z* /etc/zsh/*(.N) /etc/z*(.N) $fpath/*(.)
```

The `prompt` function is defined by `…/Prompts/promptinit`: it's part of the [prompt themes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Prompt-Themes) component. In addition to `promptinit`, you'll need the `prompt_*_setup` file for your chosen prompt theme. Look in your `~/.zshrc` for your choice of prompt theme — a call to the `prompt` function.